# How to create autoupdates software feature like firefox "check for updates" in C#

Tags: c#, installation, compilation, auto-update

How to create autoupdates software feature like firefox "check for updates" in C#?
So user doesn't need to uninstall older version program and reinstall the latest version.

Please advise.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**ClickOnce** should do just fine.

1. [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce)
2. [ClickOnce Security and Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx);

Answer (score 2):

Check out "ClickOnce":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4(VS.80).aspx

http://www.15seconds.com/issue/041229.htm